# How to grep lines which have more than specific number of special characters

Tags: linux, awk, sed, regular-expression

i would like to know what's the best way to grep lines from text which have more than specific number of special characters.

Let's say that you already know that each line have 4 comma `,` and you would like to grep lines which have more than 4 comma `,`

**Example**

```
hi,hello,how,are,you
catch,me,then,say,hello,then
```

**Output**

```
catch,me,then,say,hello,then
```

Comment: `grep -E '(.*,){5}' file`?

Comment: @Cyrus thank you and in case if you wanna grep what is less than 4 ?

Comment: also go ahead and write your comment as answer so i gonna accept it as answer.

Comment: `grep -E '^([^,]*,){,3}[^,]*$' file`? This might help: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ne 'print if tr/,// > 4'
```

- `-n` reads the file line by line
- the [tr operator](http://p3rl.org/perlop) returns the number of matches.

To print the lines with less than 4, just change `>` to `<`.

Comment: That's brilliant solution which i highly like .

Answer (score 3):

Using the `grep` command:

```
grep -E '(,.*){5}' myfile
```

does the job. Explanation:

`-E`: use an Extended Regex...

`'(,.*)`: ... to find one comma followed by any number of characters, even zero...

`{5}'`: ... and repeat the previous pattern 5 times.

If you want to grep lines with less than 4 commas, you'd need:

```
grep -xE '([^,]*,){0,3}[^,]*' myfile
```

This time, we need `-x` so the pattern is anchored at both start and end of the line so it matches the full line. And we use `[^,]*` instead of `.*` as the latter would otherwise happily match strings containing `,`s as `.` matches *any* character.

Another approach is to reverse with `-v` the previous approach. "Fewer that 4" is the same as *not* "at least 4", so:

```
grep -vE '(,.*){4}' myfile
```

Answer (score 2):

The `awk` version:

```
awk -F, 'NF > 5' myfile
```

Answer (score -1):

Achieved result by below one liner

---

```
l=`awk 'BEGIN{print }{print gsub(",","")}' example.txt |sed '/^$/d' |awk '$1 > 4 {print NR}'`;sed -n ''$l'p' example.txt
```

---

```
output
catch,me,then,say,hello,then
```